# How to edit this mySQL query so as to find people who visited specific page more than x times?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a complex (for me) MySQL query to get some data from the database.
I have 3 columns that I want to mix so as to get the data.

1. `timestamp` column
2. `url` column
3. `hash` column

My end goal is to answer these type of questions:

- How many and who are those people who visited a specific URL, in a past days range, but those people must accessed that page *x times* in that same past days range.

I have done this so far,but i do not know how to have the total for each hash

```
    SELECT DISTINCT hash
    FROM behaviour
    WHERE DATE( TIMESTAMP ) BETWEEN
    SUBDATE( CURDATE( ) , 2 ) AND CURDATE( )
    AND url =  '/used-results'
```

**AND the 'url' is found more than 2 times for this hash**

How can i edit my query so as to add the last condition?

Comment: Please post expected result set and table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count pages, you are going to need aggregation functions, somewhere along the line.  So:

```
SELECT hash
FROM behaviour
WHERE DATE( TIMESTAMP ) BETWEEN SUBDATE( CURDATE( ) , 2 ) AND CURDATE( ) AND
      url =  '/used-results'
GROUP BY hash
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

Typically a table like this would be pretty big and might have an index on `(url, TimeStamp)`.  So, the following version makes better use of hte index:

```
SELECT hash
FROM behaviour
WHERE url =  '/used-results' AND
      TIMESTAMP >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 2 DAY ) AND 
      TIMESTAMP < DATE_ADD(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 1 DAY)          
GROUP BY hash
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

Comment: thank you for this excellent answer. It works perfectly. Can you please tell me, why is it better in terms of performance not to use `DATE( TIMESTAMP ) BETWEEN SUBDATE( CURDATE( ) , 2 ) AND CURDATE( )`  ?

Comment: @villoui if the answer solved your problem, please accept it.